# Redirecting to paypal checkout page

Tags: wordpress, paypal, wordpress-theming

Am working with imevent theme template(I bought it) to build an event page.It has two registration options.1 register without paypal 2. register with paypal.The first option sends the registration details to an email. Is there a way i can then redirect to paypal to enable client to pay via credit or debit card. That is after sending registration details to a specified email.?

Comment: If you have paid for the theme, should you not contact their support before posting on Stack Overflow?

Comment: Do you have a possibility to provide a PayPal paying link in the email you send to the customer?